# svn2git error: [svn-remote "svn"] unknown

Tags: svn, github, git-svn

Trying to convert my local SVN repo to Git using `svn2git` as suggested by github.

I ran this code:
`svn2git http://localhost/repo-name`

And I got this error:

```
RA layer request failed: OPTIONS of 'http://localhost/repo-name': 200 OK (http://localhost) at /usr/bin/git-svn line 1923

[svn-remote "svn"] unknown
```

Google and a fairly thorough search in SO yielded no results.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Comment: But why you don't file:// protocol? Isn't the repository local? An intermediate layer would slow down the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the repository is local and has trunk/branches/tags layout, you may use [SubGit](http://subgit.com/):

```
$ subgit install path/to/svn/repository
```

The resulting repository will be at path/to/svn/repository/.git
It has another translation engine than svn2git (svn2git uses "git-svn" in it), so it shouldn't have this problem.

If your repository has no trunk/branches/tags layout, you may use [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) for conversion that also uses another translation engine, not git-svn.

Comment: I see. I'll test these out tomorrow when I get more time. Thanks for the feedback.